# Evaluate the increase of a variable (in Likert scale) for a subgroup of the population in a poll

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, chi-squared-test, likert

Let's say we do a poll/survey for $n=250$ people, and we study a variable in a [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) with 7 possible values (-3 to +3):

```
Person    Subgroup     Question1
1         B            -3 (strongly disagree)
2         C            0 (neutral)
3         A            2 (agree)
4         A            1 (slightly agree)
5         E            -2 (disagree)
...       ...          ...
250       A            3 (strongly agree)
```

We want to evaluate/test the hypothesis:

*"People from subgroup A tend to have a significantly higher agreement with Question1 (i.e. higher value for Question1 in Likert scale) than the general population."*

This is an unprecise "handwaving" formulation. Question:

1. **How should we reformulate this hypothesis more precisely** to be able to use usual statistical hypothesis testing tools, and be able to reject or not reject the hypothesis with $p = 0.05$, $p=0.01$, etc.?
2. Which common **statistical hypothesis testing** tools can be used in such situation?

   I know the $\chi^2$ fit test to see if an observation matches a fixed distribution (goodness of fit); or also the $\chi^2$ test for homogeneity or independance; but none of these seem to apply here.
   Or does it apply?
   Or should one use other tests? I often hear about t-test, Fisher, Kruskal-Wallis, ANOVA, Dunn, so I was curious which one to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should compare Group A with other Groups (are they B through E?) combined. **Do not**
compare Group A with *all* subjects (including Group A itself).

As you say, you could do this
using a chi-squared test, as illustrated below:

Suppose you have data roughly as below. [In `sample`, parameter `p` gives proportions
for the seven categories, which need not add to 1.]

```
set.seed(408)
a =   sample(-3:3,  50, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5))
b.e = sample(-3:3, 217, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3))
table(a)
a
-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
 3  4 10  6  5  6 16 
table(b.e)
b.e
-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
11 18 24 46 46 32 40 

TAB = rbind(c(3,4,10,5,5,6,16), c(11,18,24,46,46,32,40))
TAB
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    3    4   10    5    5    6   16
[2,]   11   18   24   46   46   32   40
```

A chi-squared test in R gives a highly significant P-value,
but with a warning message that it may not be accurate.

```
chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 11.873, df = 6, p-value = 0.06487

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB, cor = F) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

This message is shown because a couple of the expected counts
for the chi-squared test are smaller than 5:

```
chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)$exp
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5] [,6]     [,7]
[1,]  2.578947  4.052632  6.263158  9.394737  9.394737    7 10.31579
[2,] 11.421053 17.947368 27.736842 41.605263 41.605263   31 45.68421
```

Some statisticians would use the P-value if only a few expected counts
are smaller than 5, but not if any are below 3.

In R, it is possible to simulate a useful P-value, as shown below:

```
chisq.test(TAB, cor=F, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 11.873, df = NA, p-value = 0.06297
```

So it seems that the the null hypothesis could be rejected at the 10%
level, but not at the 5% level.

Of course, your data may be different from my simulated data (either more
subjects in Group A, or a more even distribution of opinions).

I wanted
you to be aware that one often runs into trouble with low expected values
if you subset the data. Also, that the option to simulate in R's `chisq.test`
is sometimes helpful.

---

*Note:* In any case, when the full $5\times 7$ table for 5 groups and 7 categories,
with 35 cells altogether, uses only 267 subjects, that's an average of 7 or 8
counts per cell, giving a high risk of expected counts that are too low.

Here is are data simulated with about twice as many subjects and the same
proportions. There is a warning message about one expected value a little below 5,
but a highly significant result with a simulated P-value. (Without simulation the possibly erroneous P-value is about 0.0001.)

[Also, not that using category numbers 1 to 7 instead of -3 to 3, facilitates making the contingency table; a 'quirk' of `tabulate`.]

```
set.seed(408)
a =   sample(1:7,  100, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5))
b.e = sample(1:7, 400, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3))
TBL = rbind(tabulate(a), tabulate(b.e))  TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    6    6   20   16    9   12   31
[2,]   17   39   62   86   74   66   56
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$exp
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]  4.6    9 16.4 20.4 16.6 15.6 17.4
[2,] 18.4   36 65.6 81.6 66.4 62.4 69.6

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL
X-squared = 22.632, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

Then you might do an *ad hoc* chi-squared test on the $2\times 2$ table (combining the lowest six categories) to target your exact issue of interest.

```
Tbl = rbind(c(69, 31), c(344, 45))
chisq.test(Tbl)$p.val
[1] 3.675252e-06
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BruceET for your detailed answer. What kind of Chi squared test is it, is it a goodness of fit one, a homogeneity one, an independance one, or another one?

Comment: Also, what is exactly the null hypothesis that is being tested with this method? I don't see exactly where is used the part of the hypothesis "agreement is *higher* for group A" in this method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The null hypothesis for this chi-squared test is that the two categorical variables (A vs. all other groups) have the same distributions. Part of doing the chi-squared test is to find expected counts $E_{ij}$ for each of the $2 \times 7$ cells. That computation uses the null hypothesis. Then the chi-squared statistic uses the formula $Q = \sum_i\sum_j \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}$ to compare observed counts $X_{ij}$ with corresponding expected counts. [There are 14 terms in the sum.] Under $H_0,$ $Q \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Chisq}(df=6),$ provided expected counts are large enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BruceET. Maybe you can edit to include this precise statement of the null hypothesis inside the question (so that everything is crystal clear) + your last remarks and the sum $Q$, or do you prefer that I do it?

Comment: Last thing: is it possible/common in such surveys to do a test *not* on "H0: The two categorical variables have the same distribution" but rather "H0: Class A has a higher agreement value than the other classes"? Not sure what kind of test to do the latter?

Comment: Not in a chi-squared 'goodness-of-fit' test. Null hypothesis is homogeneity (or sometimes independence). // Ought to be called a 'badness of fit test' because chi-squared statistic is larger for worse fits.